# About definition of characteristic polynomial f(t)

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory

Definition: A polynomial f(t) in P(F) (where P is a set of polynomials) splits over F if there are scalars $c, a_1,...,a_n$ (not necessarily distinct) in F such that $f(t)=c(t-a_1)(t-a_2) \dots (t-a_n)$.

Question: specifically, what is t, is it referring to eigenvalue?

Comment: There is no reference to linear algebra in your question, so no way to interpret anything as "an eigenvalue". The definition you give is about abstract algebra. The letter $t$ is called the indeterminate of the polynomial $f$ : see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)

Comment: @Suzet Agreed, that was just explaining the fact about factorization of polynomials, so it's just an indeterminate variable.

Comment: Since this problem, has little to with linear algebra, I've changed the tags attached to this question.